# What does stat() system call really do?

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, freebsd, nfs

I am playing around with EFS in AWS. My setup includes 2 EC2 instances (a FreeBSD 9.3 & a CentOS 7) in the same AZ - both mounting an EFS volume (let's say, at /data/efs)

I have the below code running on both instances & all files are in /data/efs -

```
for x in xrange(100):
    try:
        os.link(socket.get_hostname(), 'file')
        break
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == 17:
            # Other host is yet to unlink
            time.sleep(1)
         else:
             raise
    <do_something>
    os.unlink('file')
```

Invariably (irrespective of order of starting the script on the hosts), the linux host gets hold of control at some point & finishes "doing something" first a 100 times. Post that, FreeBSD instance takes a while (up to 1min) to start "doing something" again.

While FreeBSD host waits, running 'ls' on the host doesn't show the entry 'file' in /home/efs but still os.link() call above fails on it. But if I run os.stat() (ran it the first time to check link count), FreeBSD host starts "doing something" again immediately.

What does os.stat() really do in an NFS scenario? Does it force a recount?

Comment: Anything `os.stat` is doing is a product of the `stat` system call and NFS's response to it. This would have little or nothing to do with Python; the same effects would occur in C code using the raw system call APIs.

Comment: Agree 100% & that in fact was my query as well - 'what is stat doing'. My bad - have corrected the question.